# How to mute cross-origin iframe audio

Tags: javascript

I have used cross-origin iframe in my web page,

how can i mute the audio of the iframe

and is it possible access the ifram source.

i have tried the following for mute and get source of the iframe

```
<iframe id="Iframe" src="#someurl" style="width:1024px;height:768px;volume:silent" hidden></iframe>

document.getElementById('Iframe').contentWindow.targetFunction();

$("#Iframe").attr("src", "http://some");
```

Comment: no, cross origin access is forbidden for security reasons - however, if you "control" **both** sites, you can implement communication between page and iframe using window.postMessage

Comment: what shall you try? are able to make changes to **both** sites? If not, there's **nothing** to try at all

Comment: yes i am going to make both sites

Comment: I recommend you removing any `iframe`s from your site unless they are absolutely needed. This isn't the 90's, we don't need them anymore because they only give us more headaches.

Comment: i need iframe in my site

Answer (score 1):

i got solution for communicate cross-origin

```
//the iframe code
       setInterval(function() {
              parent.postMessage("Hello","http://davidwalsh.name");
       },1000);

//The parent code
       $(window).on('message', function(e){
            console.log('parent received message!:  ',e.originalEvent.data);
        });
```